# Wordpress : html code below content

Tags: php, wordpress

i developed a plugin for WordPress. In this plugin i generate a html code and add this to the post. Have anybody a idea for adding generated HTML under the content/post field? now i generate the code and add this directly below the content with this method:

`add_filter('the_content', array('xxx', 'custom_content_after_post'));`

Here is a picture of my wanted plan:

[image]

Comment: do you need you HTML below comment box? if yes then it's not good because when you have more number of comments then user cannot see your HTML.

Comment: you´re right. i think this is confused after post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Your html will be added after comment form

**in function.php**

```
add_action( 'comment_form','my_form_func' );
function my_form_func($args){    
    ?>
    <h2>This is my html text</h2>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you. This solve my problem. But can my plugin do this automatically after i install the plugin?

Comment: Yes it can do this

Comment: :) okay. have you a idea?

Comment: it is simple just paste code inside plugin file..:)..hope it works. thx